# Set value for group by order

Tags: sql, google-bigquery, gaps-and-islands

I have SQL table with columns COL_1, COL_2:

| COL_1 | COL_2 | COL_3 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| a | 2021-09-11 14:25:15.699 | 1 |
| b | 2021-09-11 14:25:36.489 | 2 |
| a | 2021-09-11 14:33:36.500 | 3 |
| a | 2021-09-11 14:36:24.915 | 3 |
| a | 2021-09-11 14:36:38.900 | 3 |
| a | 2021-09-11 14:36:54.905 | 3 |
| c | 2021-09-11 14:37:09.092 | 4 |
| a | 2021-09-11 14:39:09.111 | 5 |
| d | 2021-09-11 14:39:30.292 | 6 |

I need to get COL_3. I got column 4 by grouping column 1 and sorting by date (column 2), if the group changes, I assign a new index for the following groups.

Comment: You could look at `LAG`

Comment: @Nathan_Sav I try lots of queries with lag, but none succeeded

Comment: @Milos-Bijanic; this comment is not useful, LAG function works as documented (at least for SQL Server). If you had any difficulties you should add the query you tried.

Comment: @userMT It won't help much if I put the queries in, because none of them are close to the solution.

Comment: You mention "if the group changes"....what is the group? Whatever you are trying to do here is probably pretty easy but it is not at all clear what you are trying to do.

Comment: @SeanLange; I hope you are right and that what I am looking for is really easy.
1) I sort by date (col_2).
2) I pass through each row of column_1, and start the value of the column_3 with 1, if the next row of column_1 have the same value as previous row of column_1, value for that row in column_3 have also value 1, if not I increase value for 1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**This is a classic *gaps-and-islands* problem.**

There are many solutions. A common one is to use `LAG` to identify rows which change value, then a conditional windowed `COUNT` to assign the group numbers

```sql
WITH PrevValues AS (
    SELECT *,
      LAG(COL_1) OVER (ORDER BY COL_2) AS PrevCol1
    FROM YourTable t
)
SELECT COL_1,COL_2,COL_3,
  COUNT(CASE WHEN PrevCol1 = COL_1 THEN NULL ELSE 1 END)
      OVER (ORDER BY COL_2 ROWS UNBOUNDED PRECEDING) AS New_Col_3
FROM PrevValues t
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=cd48c6aee4b385cc0051f564c28d906b)

Comment: This solves my problem. Thanks a lot!